# Macro to copy column I, F, G from one worksheet into column A, B and C

Tags: excel, vba

Really new to VBA, wondering how to write a macro to copy column I, F, G from one worksheet into column A, B and C?

Comment: What have you tried? This should be a fairly simple task that you would be able to find the answer to in a search engine. You could try recording a macro, then doing the copy, stopping the macro and inspecting the recorded macro as a starting point.

Comment: Record a macro while you copy/paste your columns then press Alt+F8 and click on the edit option.  This will open the VBA IDE where you can review the code to gain an idea of how VBA works.  Chances are the recorded macro will contain lots of `Activate` and `Select` commands which, over time, you will learn to eliminate.  Google is a handy tool for beginners too.  Obtain a good beginner's VBA tutorial or book.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub cpy()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I:I").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F:F").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B") 
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G:G").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C:C")

End Sub
```